Is it possible to generate a inventory report as json?
I am trying to develop a CRM with an Inventory Management System integrating the Amazon SP-API.
I am doing this with nodejs and expressjs.
I want to generate inventory reports and I´ve tried different endpoints but none of them provides me the correct information or format.
I am using the Reports Api, where I need to first generate a report using the endpoint
POST /reports/2021-06-30/reports
Then get the reportId and get the reportDocumentId
GET /reports/2021-06-30/reports/{reportId}
For then generating the csv file with the report
GET /reports/2021-06-30/documents/{reportDocumentId}
The thing is that it is a long process and low performant.
Is there a way to generate an inventory report rather than this way?
I have also tried the FBA Inventory API but it is really unprecise. It returns an inventory that does not match the one I have in my seller account.
GET /fba/inventory/v1/summaries
The thing is that this is a really slow and long process to generate a report and store it in my database for then late displaying it in a table in a dashboard
